# Prove that the intersection of all maximal left ideals of a ring $R$ is a two sided ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Prove that the intersection of all maximal left ideals of a ring $R$ is a two sided ideal.

What i did:Suppose $B$ be the intersection of all maximal left ideals of the ring $R$. Clearly $B$ is a left ideal,so we only have to prove that if $b \in B$, $r \in R$ imply $br \in R$. Equivalently if there is a maximal left ideal $M$ with $br \notin M$, then $ \exists $ a maximal left ideal $A$ with $b \notin A$.Give some idea to show such $A$ will exist.

Comment: There is a characterization of this famous ideal ( the Jacobson radical) that makes this fact obvious.

Comment: sorry i don't know about that

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical

Comment: @rschwieb Could there be another (and more direct) proof of the fact that the intersection is a two-sided ideals, without characterizing it as intersection of annihilators? My point is, it seems not every answer to the present question would fit under the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Dear @carebear : I have never seen a strategy simpler than that one, but let me know if you find one.

Comment: @rschwieb Is is not possible to proceed my idea further somehow?

Comment: @ArpitKansal : I know the feeling: it seems like it should have an elementary answer. My experience, though, is that time spent in this direction for this particular problem usually exceeds the time required to use the alternate method by a lot.